# Can we get public key using Paramiko? Or just read it like plain text?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm writing a python program to get rsa public key. Is there a way to get it via paramiko or I just read it like plain text and with the assumption from id_rsa.pub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know where the public key file is located, Paramiko can't help you either - it also needs you to specify where it is.  You can of course try the usual places (starting by parsing ~/.ssh/config if available), but you don't need Paramiko for that.

Comment: cool. i thought paramiko might have some function that search for it or sth. now i know is just a plain text reading of the file. thanks.